Change elements of a vector with a set probability
I am looking for a way to change the elements of a vector with a set probability. Take as an example this probability and vector:
p <- 0.5
v1 <- 1:10

I know that I can now change every element of the vector and add 2 to it, for example. But how can I change each element only with the probability p? So that in the end, there will be a vector in which statistically half of the elements are the same as before, and half had +2 added to them?
As I was looking for answers, all I could find was ways to calculate a probability, not set it; ways to change the entire vector; and ways to change specific elements, but not random elements chosen with a set probability.

From what you say, I think your use of "probability" may be confusing here. I think you want "proportion".  For example, I think you want "... such that there will be a vector in which a proportion, p, of the elements will have the value 2 added and (1 - p) will be unchanged. Am I correct in this assumption?

@Edward yes, thank you. That is what I want to do.

You can sample the indices of v1 that are less than (p * its length) and use that to index the original vector:
p <- 0.5
v1 <- 1:10

set.seed(123)

add_2 <- sample(seq_along(v1) <= p * length(v1))
v1[add_2] <- v1[add_2] + 2
v1
[1]  3  2  5  4  5  6  9  8 11 12


As per the comment, you mean "proportion" instead of "probability", you could use
v1 + 2 * seq_along(v1) %in% sample(length(v1), length(v1) * p)


You can use sample like below
v1 + sample(c(0, 2), length(v1), c(1 - p, p), replace = TRUE)


This gives results that are too random. See the comments above.

@Edward see the update
